# Get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, insert

I want to get the Unique ID for the Last Inserted Row inside stored procedure, I make like this

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE addNewUsers(IN userName varchar(128),IN password varchar(128), IN addedBy INT)

BEGIN

 DECLARE id int default 0;

  id = mysqli_insert_id (insert into  `system_users`( `username`,`password`) values (userName ,md5(password)) );
  IF id <> 0 THEN     
        insert into  `user_profile`( `full_name`,`Date_time_ added`,`added_by`) values (userName ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),addedBy ) where `user_id`=id ;
  END IF


END //

DELIMITER ;
```

This error occur

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= mysqli_insert_id (insert into `system_users`( `username`,`password`) values (' at line 7
```

I doubt it's from `mysqli_insert_id` , what should I do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) is the problem, you're writing a MySQL stored procedure, not PHP. You want to use the [`last_insert_id()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

> `LAST_INSERT_ID()` (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column as a result of the most recently executed `INSERT` statement.

You also need to fix your assignment syntax. Something more like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE addNewUsers(IN userName varchar(128),IN password varchar(128), IN addedBy INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE id int default 0;

  insert into  `system_users`( `username`,`password`) values (userName ,md5(password));
  set id = last_insert_id();
  if id <> 0 then
    -- ...
```