# using comment ID to associate images with comment

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a site where comments can be added in reply to an initial post and each comment can have attached images (and likely will given the type of content). I'm wondering how I will grab the proper comment ID to insert it into a MySQL DB column in the image table.

So far the db has a table for the initial post with serial as the primary key, the db also has an image table with id as the primary and columns for various attributes of the image as well as a column for the serial of the post images belong to (serial comes from the serial of the item the post is about), I plan to also add a column to that table for the comment ID which will be filled with the ID of the comment they belong to if they don't just belong to the initial post. I'd like to add comments in their own table with ID, info, date and title.

What I'm unsure of is when inserting a comment with attached image, how do I grab the comment ID to insert into the image table comment ID column? Or is there a better way to approach the issue?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You pass each value into a procedure which within transaction logic inserts the comment gets the ID as output and then uses that as input for the image.  On failure it rolls all back on success it commits.

Comment: So @xQbert does that mean I should have the comment inserted then use a DB call to grab the ID for use with the image insert and if the image handling fails have the function delete the comment and throw an error?

Comment: a simple example with an auto increment Id.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151861/fetch-last-inserted-id-form-stored-procedure-in-mysql or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310442/get-the-unique-id-for-the-last-inserted-row or [mySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/getting-unique-id.html)  To answer direct question:... I would call a procedure passing in the comment, imageName etc.  within the procedure it would insert into the comment table, obtain the last Id and then insert into the image table.  If it both updates work commit the transaction else roll back.